# Heap corruption error after language pack installation for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2012

I have installed the german version of Visual Studio 2012 Premium on my german windows machine and installed the english language pack vor Visual Studio 2012 Premium and it works great but after I installed the german language pack I get the heap corruption error 0xc0000374. The faulty module is ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16408

Only restoring Windows resolves this issue.

**Edit:**
This error also occurs when changing the displayed language and I was able to observe this behavior only after updating from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and updating from DevExpress 12.1 to DevExpress 13.1.

Not only that, but the error does not occure immediately after installing a language, sometimes I can start debugging my program as usual and then after three to five times or so, the error occurs.

Is there another solution than restoring Windows?

Comment: Thanks for the information, but you may have missed the point of this website. The website is a Q&A site, the post at the top (your post in this case) being the question; I don't think you've not really understood the Q bit!

Comment: create a dump and share the dump: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57